Source that Sarah laughed because she heard that the bracha for children was only temporary i.e. "You call that a bracha?"
In this answer I quote a lecture by Rabbi Manis Friedman, where he explains that Sarah heard that the beracha from the angel was only going to be temporary. Her laughter was a form of protest; a mother praying for and defending her child.
She knew this because a true beracha is meant to be given to the one being blessed, personally, but instead her beracha was actually told to Avraham. The lack of permanence was because of the Akeida - she was right and sensed that her son would die young.
Thus the angel reassured her that he would personally return and ensure that the child would be ok. This very same angel was the one who appeared as Avraham was about to slaughter Yitzchak, and stopped him.
A few more details:

She was a greater prophetess than Avraham, which is why she figured it out but he didn't
Part of it was also due to the difference. He was a "seer", she was a "hearer". She heard that the beracha was off
A similar thing happened with the Shunamit woman, who also heard that her son would die young, from the wording of the beracha: "you will coddle a child". She didn't want to just coddle a child, she wanted him to grow up! So Elisha reassured her that he would personally see to it that he doesn't die young. When he died young, Elisha resurrected him

This is clearly from a sicha or a maamar. I could ask Rabbi Friedman but I would like the answer ASAP, and it takes time for me to get hold of him, and I try not to disturb him for scattered sources if possible. My own Baal Chassidus Rav is on holiday, but I have asked a few others (if they get back to me, I will answer my own question)
So, does anyone know where I can find the (or a) source for these ideas?

https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35579&st=&pgnum=30 says something very similar on the pasuk ותכחש שרה

@JoelK even if some or all of the OP is Rabbi Friedman's chiddush, the answer in your source is certainly enough to give the underlying principle of what Rabbi Friedman is saying a pretty firm basis.

@JoelK also, with regards to "a blessing should only go to the one intended", I see support for this in Hilchot Tefilla and the blessings of the Cohanim - they must face the ones being blessed, and it must be direct (see also Ohr Hachaim on 18:10). Yismach Moshe on 20:3 states that the blessing was indeed intended exclusively for Sarah, not Avraham. The Chassidic angle on this is that turns out, giving the bracha to Avraham was essential for Yitzchak, and Sarah didn't realise that, so her instincts may have been right, but this was an exceptional situation. I think this support is enough.

Here is the drasha I ended up writing, that answers this question and quotes various sources to back it up:

As we said in Parashat VeZot HaBeracha, each year of our life, we
learn something new, deeper and more mature about the events and
personalities in the Torah. This week, I would like to present a new
perspective on Avraham and Sarah, one that takes us to a higher level
of appreciation of the gadlut. I want to defend them, as in this
week’s parasha, we find they both do something questionable, and as a
result, people view them negatively as a result, chas veshalom. I like
to always try to defend the Kadmonim, because we know that they were
on the highest madregot, yet sometimes the Torah, the commentaries,
and people in general, present a negative view of them, often one that
is hard to understand given how holy and flawless they are!
So I will start with Sarah Immenu. In this week’s parasha, she is
informed that she will have a child in her old age, and, famously, she
laughs. The standard understanding is disbelief. We are taught from a
young age that she shouldn’t have laughed, because even though she was
too old to have children, she should trust in Hashem, because He can
do anything. This doesn’t make sense, that Sarah, a greater prophetess
than Avraham, would think Hashem couldn’t make her pregnant? That’s
not giving her the credit she deserves.
As we get older, we learn that it’s not so much that she didn’t
believe that Hashem could give her a child, but that she felt she
didn’t deserve such a spectacular miracle. Better, yes, but at the end
of the day, this now becomes a violation of Bitachon. We see time and
again, when someone turns to Hashem and says “Katonti- I am not
worthy”, this is counted against them.
It may sound like a praise – they were so humble that they truly
believed they were not worthy, but it counts as a sin because we must
factor in that we are in a relationship with Hashem. In a
relationship, trust is essential. If my wife says she will do
something for me, and I say “I doubt you will, because I will end up
blowing it by being a bad husband”; if one party in a relationship is
convinced their partner doesn't love them really, and He is
constantly weighing their merits against their demerits, with His
love, favours and promises all contingent on the scale being on the
side of merit, then there is something that needs correcting in this
relationship, to say the least.
So, this is the real answer: Sarah didn’t laugh out of disbelief. She
laughed because she heard something wrong with the bracha. A bracha
should be given face to face, according to Hilchot Tefilla and the
blessings of the Cohanim, as well as Ohr Hachaim’s commentary on the
Pasuk. But the bracha, which was exclusively for her according to
Yismach Moshe, was given to her husband and she therefore sensed that
it was only a temporary bracha. She was right, Yitzchak was destined
to die during the Akeda, so she lobbied for him, like a true, devoted
mama. She laughed, saying “you call that a bracha?” And it worked, the
angel reassured her that he would personally see to it that the child
would live, and indeed the same angel is the one who came to Avraham
to tell him to not put his hand against Yitzchak!
Sarah was a greater prophetess than Avraham, and she was a “hearer”,
"Sarah heard", whereas Avraham was a seer "he raised his eyes and he
saw", which is why she sensed it, and Avraham missed it. She heard
something wrong with the bracha, similar to how the Shunamit woman
heard something wrong with her bracha – “you will coddle a child”. She
wanted a child who would grow up, not just be coddled, and indeed
Elisha promised her that he would ensure this, and when the boy died,
Elisha resurrected him. See אמרי נועם עה"ת, for more support (thanks Joel K).

